# Laravel Livewire Magic Action not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am new in laravel livewire. I'm trying to set value of variable using livewire.
In my livewire controller I have defined public variable.

```
public $baction;
```

in my livewire view is like this

```
<p>
Hello
{{$baction}}
</p>
<button wire:click="$set('baction', 1)" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center">
    Set
</button>
```

Now when I click on button it should set value of `$baction` variable to 1 and it should show next to Hello text, but it's not showing.

Comment: Does `$baction` show at all? If not, can you show your full component.

Comment: Are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: Yes I set $baction any value it shows but nothing happening on button click & also no error in console

Comment: one thing my button also have this event @click="Button='add'" wire:click="$set('baction', 1)"
do you think @click is making issue? even I remove this but its still not working

Comment: Are you mixing livewire with vuejs?

Comment: NO I dont have vuejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code example works fine.
I believe you forgot to include the livewire CSS and JS in the blade that displays your livewire component

```
<html>
 <head>
   .....
   @livewireStyles
 </head>
 <body>
   
   <livewire:my-awesome-component />

   @livewireScripts
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks but its included and other elements are working fine